# Python: Memory-efficient matrix creation for sets of 1's, -1's, and 0s to be optimized by scipy least squares

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, scipy

I'm iterating through a list of strings and translating them into arrays of 1's, -1's, and 0's. For example - I may have the following list:

```
A,B,-C
A,-D
B,C,-D
```

Which will become a "biglist" equal to:

```
[
 [1  1 -1  0],
 [1  0  0 -1],
 [0  1  1 -1]
]
```

At the moment, I'm simply looping through every line of strings, assigning values of 1 or -1 to the string if it is unique, and zeroing out the ones that do not exist (for example, D is not present in the first line, so it is 0). The silly way I'm doing the above is basically:

```
for line_of_strings in all_strings:
    for the_string in line_of_strings:
        entry[string_index] = (1 or -1)

    biglist.append(entry)
```

Eventually, I have a nice set of lists on which I run:

```
scipy.optimize.nnls(biglist)
```

This works, but winds up taking up a truckload of memory and time. Is there a more efficient way to go about this? Using numpy or scipy arrays/matrices, perhaps?

Comment: just checking: are A,B,C,D strings which are equal (if present) on each "line"? In that case, I think you meant "I have a list of lists of strings" in the beggining?

Comment: You could try storing the data as a sparse matrix: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: Also, have you checked that what is taking "a truckoad of memory and time" is your array creation, and not the nnls solver? How big are these lists?

Comment: @Blender does `scipy.optimize.nnls` understand sparse matrices as arguments?

Comment: @goncalopp Each row could have a different amount of strings, which aren't always equal. So yes, it's basically a big list of lists. I've done some memory profiling, and though the array itself doesn't take very long to generate, it does hold about 1GB while the program runs. NNLS takes up the rest, which can easily exceed 6GBs. It seems far too excessive.

Comment: If I understood correctly, if your list of lists has m "lines" and n different strings (total), your final array will be m*n, correct? This doesn't sound that big. If you store your data properly with numpy instead of python lists, with int8, this should take m*n bytes. Only 100000 lines * 10000 unique strings would take 1 GB. does this sound similar to the sizes you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy arrays instead of lists seems to make quite a bit of difference timewise, at least in a trivial example:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"from scipy.optimize import nnls; m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]; b=[1, 2, 3]" "nnls(m, b)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.5 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; from scipy.optimize import nnls; m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]); b=[1, 2, 3]" "nnls(m, b)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 20 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; from scipy.optimize import nnls; m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]); b=np.array([1, 2, 3])" "nnls(m, b)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.4 usec per loop
```

I'd expect that numpy arrays would have smaller memory footprint as well. If your input is reasonably sparse, and if the performance is still not satisfactory, it might be worth investigating if `nnls` accepts sparse matrices.

Comment: I don't think `nnls` handles sparse matrices; there's [`scipy.sparse.linalg`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html) for that. Also note that matrices must contain some 80% zeros for sparse matrices to pay off.

Comment: @larsmans good to know! Just for my curiosity: Can you elaborate on this magic number 0.8?

Comment: It's a very crude guideline based on the memory overhead of sparse representations and the more complicated algorithms needed to perform operations like dot products on them. CSR and CSC, which I consider the main sparse formats, require two index arrays alongside an array of non-zero values, which take up more space as the number of nonzeros increases. A fully dense matrix in the CSR format can take up to three times the memory of the corresponding `np.ndarray`, IIRC.

Comment: I haven't done a true test on this, but there will most definitely be >80% zeroes in the matrix. I'm using nnls to prevent negative values, so I'd have to check if there's a sparse version of that.