# Swap rows csr_matrix scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a 256x256 csr_matrix in scipy and I have a list of a new row order that I'd like to apply.  I tried this:

```
def HblockDiag(z):
        Hz = H(z) # H(z) returns a 256x256 csr_matrix
        Hz.indices = idenRows
        return Hz
```

but it didn't work work because `indices` doesn't give the indices of each row...  What's the best way to do this?

---

Edit:

```
def HblockDiag(H, idenRows):
    x = H.tocoo()
    idenRows = np.asarray(idenRows, dtype=x.row.dtype)
    x.row = idenRows[x.row]
    H = x.tocsr()
    return H

test = sps.csr_matrix([[1,2,4],[6,3,4],[8,5,2]])
print test.toarray()
test = HblockDiag(test, [2,0,1])
print test.toarray()
```

I get:

```
[[1 2 4]
 [6 3 4]
 [8 5 2]]
[[6 3 4]
 [8 5 2]
 [1 2 4]]
```

instead, I would like to get:

```
[[8 5 2]
 [1 2 4]
 [6 3 4]]
```

Comment: What is `idenRows`?  Unless you understand the `csr` format, it is better to use indexing, rather trying to modify the attributes directly.

Comment: `idenRows` is a vector with the new orde of rows.  So: [0,1,3,2]
would swap rows 2 and 3.  (that was just an example, `idenRows` is actually 256 elements long)

Comment: Just to be sure: is the desired result `[[8 5 2], [1 2 4], [6 3 4]]`? If so, please edit the question to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Convert from CSR to COO format.

  ```
  x = Hz.tocoo()
  ```

  Per the doc string, `sparse.coo_matrix.__doc__`, COO  has "very fast conversion to and from CSR/CSC formats".
- Permute the rows of the COO matrix

  ```
  idenRows = np.argsort(idenRows)
  x.row = idenRows[x.row]
  ```
- Convert from COO back to CSR

  ```
  Hz = x.tocsr()
  ```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

def HblockDiag(H, idenRows):
    x = H.tocoo()
    idenRows = np.argsort(idenRows)
    idenRows = np.asarray(idenRows, dtype=x.row.dtype)
    x.row = idenRows[x.row]
    H = x.tocsr()
    return H

test = sps.csr_matrix([[1,2,4],[6,3,4],[8,5,2]])
print test.toarray()
# [[1 2 4]
#  [6 3 4]
#  [8 5 2]]

test = HblockDiag(test, [2,0,1])
print test.toarray()
```

yields

```
[[8 5 2]
 [1 2 4]
 [6 3 4]]
```

---

PS. Generally, sparse matrices are used only when the size of the matrix is very large. It's not clear why you would want to use a sparse matrix if the shape is only (256, 256). Also, matrices should contain [at least 80% zeros for sparse matrices to pay off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336443/190597).

Comment: Not sure it worked (see my edit).  Thank you though!

Comment: I'm guessing you want `[[8 5 2], [1 2 4], [6 3 4]]`. In that case, use `idenRows = np.argsort(idenRows)` to convert `idenRows` to the right values for indexing with `x.row = idenRows[x.row]`.